# MOSFET problem in H-Bridge circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, h-bridge, inductive

I'm trying to switch the latching solenoid on and off with an H-bridge circuit (see figure).

[image: H-bridge circuit]

Components I use in this circuit: [P-MOS](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panjit-international-inc/PJA3405-R1-00001/14660219) , [N-MOS](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panjit-international-inc/PJA3404-R1-00001/14660647?s=N4IgTCBcDaIAoCkCCBmALABjQfQEoEZsNiN8QBdAXyA) , [NPN](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/micro-commercial-co/MMBT3904-TP/717280?s=N4IgTCBcDaILJwEIBUDMBOADAFgLQBcAHEAXQF8g)

I've run this circuit a few times with no problems, I turn the solenoid on and off. However, after turning it on and off a few times, one of the P-MOS gets hot and breaks down. Since MOSFETs have body diodes in themselves, I didn't connect the diode again to the circuit.

Should I add 4 diodes to protect MOSFETs from inductive load? This is the only solution I can think of. If you have another suggestion, I'd like to explore it.

- When I supply the solenoid with 12V from the power supply, it consumes a maximum of 2.6A current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If you have another suggestion, I'd like to explore it.*

1. Make sure you have a bulk capacitor connected close to the H-bridge power terminals to catch the reverse energy when the solenoid is switched. It could be that your 12 volt power supply is incapable of soaking up this energy return and it's rising significantly above 12 volts and damaging the PMOS ([PJA3405_R1_00001](https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/PJA3405.pdf)) devices.
2. The PMOS is also a little light-weight on reverse diode current; the diode is only rated at 1.5 amps continuous current and this is less than half the rating for the MOSFET's forward conduction so, maybe add extra diodes or choose a better MOSFET.
3. The maximum power dissipation for the MOSFET is 1.25 watts **AND** the data sheet has no SOA (safe operating area) curve. This concerns me because, when the reverse diode conducts (2.6 amps) it will have a forward volt drop of about 0.85 volts (see fig 6 in data sheet) and this is a peak power of 2.21 watts i.e. greater than the absolute max power rating.

The NMOS device appears to have a better rating in this critical areas: -

- Continuous current of 5.6 amps

Comment: I'd like to add a few things about the max dissipation of the PMOS: Because of it's on-state dissipation it'll be hot (about 0.4W brings a delta-T of 40°C), so the max power dissipation should be de-rated (e.g. less than 1 Watt). Not to mention the increase of on-resistance under these conditions.

Comment: Andy aka, I am supplying the circuit with a 3.6V battery and increase the 3.6V to 12V with a booster circuit. I'm storing this voltage in a 4700uF 16V capacitor. So as you said in [1], I have a capacitor. I will check P-MOS datasheet again

Comment: @harmonica make sure that the connection between 4700 uF and H-bridge is short and, supplement the decoupling (close to the bridge) with ceramic capacitors of 1 uF and 10 nF to ensure minimal inductive reactance.

Comment: @Andyaka, After adding extra diodes, all MOSFETs (P-MOS and N-MOS) broken... I guess I must select new MOSFETs

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you are just pushing them too hard. Of course, if you had more copper on the drain and source connections you would remove more heat. Try and pick MOSFETs that have a safe operating area curve in their data sheet too.

Comment: Are there any MOSFETs that you have used before that will meet these conditions and that you can recommend?

Comment: @harmonica I'm a big-MOSFET guy (circa 1200 volts and 200 amps) but many supplier data bases (Farnell, RS, Digikey and Mouser) have great selection tools. If you find one, leave a comment and I'll check it out.

Comment: It will arrive the fastest in my country and looks like the best P-MOS is DMP3056L-7. However, according to the information you provided, this is also not enough.

Comment: It can be tricky to get right. It's probably OK for the current if you have sufficient copper around the device on the PCB (see note 5 on page 2 of data sheet). However, if the device is only being switched intermittently you may get away with less copper. This size of package is looking borderline for your application I reckon.

Comment: I will use latch solenoid and according to datasheet of solenoid 60ms is enough to switch the solenoid on and off. My PCB is 1oz, 2 layer with ground pouring

Comment: You need copper attached to the collector pin to get the best dissipation from the devices.

Comment: @Andyaka, I'm thinking of redesigning the PCB and using high current MOSFETs like DMPH6050SK3. I wanted to use SOT-23 packet MOSFET but it would be good to have a look at other packages. Thank you for all the information